# printing reference variable is not printing the object's address

Tags: java

> Which of the following is TRUE with respect to reference variables?
>
> (i)   Printing a reference will NOT print the address of the object 
>     referred by it
>
> (ii)  Printing a reference will  print the address of the object 
>     referred by it
>
> (iii) & operator CANNOT be used on reference variables to print 
>     their address
>
> (iv)  & operator can be used on reference variables to print their
>     address
>
> Answer: i and iii

but according to me reference is a pointer which points to the address of the object. so when it is printed directly, it should print the address of that object and using & with reference variable will print its own address.

Comment: Well have you tried it? A reference is "some way of getting to the object" - it doesn't have to be a raw pointer. And no, using `&` with a reference type variable will simply fail to compile. It seems to me that you could have verified both of these pretty easily yourself.

Comment: i am new at java and i am applying the c++ concepts.

Comment: @JonSkeet can i store the address of an object in some other variable than refernce? if no, then it should be a raw pointer

Comment: Java isn't C++. Don't assume that things which are true in C++ are true in Java. You can store a *reference* to an object in a variable, and copy that reference around. That doesn't mean it's a raw pointer, although it may be. But even if it *is* a raw pointer, that doesn't mean that you can use the `&` operator with it, nor does it mean that you can print out the pointer. Nor does it explain why you didn't just *try* these things...

Comment: now suppose if i want to know the memory address of the object being created. how can i accomplish this?

Comment: Java is _always_ pass-by-value.

Comment: @rakeshkumar The Java language doesn't offer a mechanism for finding out the address of something. (But it is designed so that you can write very large and elaborate programs without ever needing to know an object's address.)

Answer (score 3):

When you use [System.out.print()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.Object%29) to print an object reference. Internally it uses `String.valueOf(object)` to print the object. `String.valueOf(object)` internally calls `object.toString()` method which will call the default implementation of the [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) defined in the `Object` class, if you have not overridden the `toString()` in your class.

As per the Javadocs ,

*The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.*

Now if you look into the Javadocs for [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29), it says

*As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (**This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.**)*

Hence you don't actually print the address of the object referenced.

Secondly , `&` is just a bitwise AND operator. It **ANDs** the individual bits of the two operands it operates upon. You cannot use it on a single object reference variable.Refer the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) to know more about the use of `&` operator.

Answer (score 2):

So, it seems that you disagree with the given answer of that multiple choice answer. Consider this:

```
String s = "Hello world.";
System.out.println(s);
```

`s` is of type `String`, which is a class, which is a reference type in Java. Yet when you print `s`, you get the string printed, not the address. So, (i) is true and not (ii).

Regarding the `&` operator, there are things you need to understand.

- First off, reference to an object does not mean a pointer to an object. It could (*theoretically*) be a double pointer, it could be a triple pointer with an offset, or anything else, as long as it references the object by some specific convention. Of course, the simplest convention is a direct pointer to the object, but the Java language doesn't bother to spell that out (as far as I know) because it's an implementation thing.
- Java is a different language than C and C++, so it defines its own semantics for the operators. So, to put it simply, in Java, `&` is not the "address of" operator because the language designers have defined it like that. There is no "address of" operator regardless of whether references as implemented as simple pointers. The philosophy behind this is, of course, avoidance of pointer arithmetic and memory safety.

So, again, it's (iii) and not (iv).

Comment: thank you very much. this was very well elaborated. 

now you have raised one more doubt in my mind, what is this double and triple pointer and you said it could be a double or triple pointer too. does this mean it should be a pointer?

Comment: @rakeshkumar They were just examples of what else it could *theoretically* be. They are definitely **not true** in practice for Java.