# why hashCode() gives different output for same object in java?

Tags: java, hashcode

I have this code

```
class A
{
 public static void main(String reds[])
  {
    A ob=new A();
    System.out.println("Object "+ob);
    System.out.println("HashCode "+ob.hashCode());
  }
}
```

Output is:
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2aCR.png)

The output for above code gives different value most of the time. 
Also, the below link mentions that printing a reference variable prints *ClassName@hashcode*.

[printing reference variable is not printing the object's address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757390/printing-reference-variable-is-not-printing-the-objects-address)

However, the output for printing reference varibale differs from hashCode().What is actually happening here?

Just wanted to clear my concepts of hashcode in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `println()` on your object (of type `A`), it prints `getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())` (which is the default implementation of `toString()` in Object class) i.e, it converts hashCode to *hexString*. If you do the same for your hashCode (when printing), you will get the same value.

If your class overrides `toString`, then it will be printed.

Comment: Also, directly printing an object using println() calls its toString() method which does mentioned tasks.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar - Yes. It calls `Object's toString` if your class (or any of its direct parents) don't override `toString()`

Comment: It prints the result of calling `A.toString()`, whatever that may be. In this case it wasn't overridden, so it printed the result of `Object.toString()`. None of this behaviour is attributable to `println()`.

Comment: @EJP - I thought that the OP's question was how `className@someHexVal` was being generated. Edited my answer to add the `toString` part

Answer (score 0):

`Object.toString()` uses the hashCode in hex. You are printing it yourself in decimal.